# Table: rule spanning two side-by-side tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, booktabs

I have a little problem for which I desperately need help. Basically I want to span a `midrule` (or any other type of rule) over two vertically aligned side-by-side tables. As in the MWE below, I could just put the `midrule` outside the `tabularx` environment and get the result I want. However, doing so produces a `misplaced \noalign` error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\midrule\midrule
    \begin{tabularx}{.49\textwidth}[t]{Xr}
    header 1 & header 2\\ \midrule
    row 1    & row 1\\
    \end{tabularx}%
\hfill
    \begin{tabularx}{.49\textwidth}[t]{Xr}
    header 1 & header 2\\ \midrule
    row 1    & row 1\\
    row 2    & row 2\\
    \end{tabularx}
\midrule\midrule
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this properly would be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: `\hrule` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With \midrule from booktabs, you have to put your tabularx environments in a tabular one:

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage{lmodern} 
 \usepackage[showframe, noheadfoot, nomarginpar, textwidth = 15cm, textheight = 23cm] {geometry} 
 \usepackage{array,tabularx}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \newlength{\tabsep}
 \setlength{\tabsep}{\dimexpr \textwidth -0.49\textwidth-0.49\textwidth \relax}
 \pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{document}
 \mbox{}

 \begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{@{}c @{\hspace{\tabsep}}c@{}}%
     \midrule\midrule
     \begin{tabularx}{.49\textwidth}[t]{Xr}
     header 1 & header 2\\ \midrule
     row 1    & row 1\\
     \end{tabularx}%
&
    \begin{tabularx}{.49\textwidth}[t]{Xr}
    header 1 & header 2\\ \midrule
    row 1    & row 1\\
    row 2    & row 2\\
    \end{tabularx}\\
    \midrule\midrule
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Resulting in:]